# Can't connect to mysql in centos

Tags: java, mysql, linux, spring, mybatis

I use `Spring+Mybatis` and try to connect mysql server 5.1 in Centos.
The Connection of mysqldatabase is ok and there is no problem when I'm testing with Test Class.
And There is no problem when connecting MYSQL5.5 in Window Server with same config.

In Connecting to MYSQL5.1 in Centos,
When my web application project make a select query, an exception is occurred.

```
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'nmnl.USR' doesn't exist
```

How can I solve?

This is config in spring-beans.xml.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<util:properties id="SQL_ERROR_CODE" location="classpath:SQL_ERROR_CODE.properties" />

<util:properties id="APPLICATION_CONFIG" location="classpath:APPLICATION_CONFIG.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.99:3306/nmnl?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:sqlmap-config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Check your table mapping with the POJO. Also check if there is a table in the db.

Comment: Table mapping, POJO and table is exist. It is alerady ok when testing with main class (JDBC). I think it will be cause of my batis.

Comment: I mean check if there is a typo in table mapping

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether table USR exist in nmnl database or not. Because exception says table USR not exists in nmnl.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I got it.
When i restore database with query,My query is CREATE `USR`.
I remove this char ` and restore back.

And I changed all table names to UPPER case.

Answer (score 0):

I soled. MySQL in linux has case-sensitive. There is only can choose upper or lower. My queries in mybatis sql map are both lower and upper. So i was changed all to UPPER cases.